# fail to loadjava on Oracle and dbms_java.grant_permission not working

Tags: java, oracle

I was trying to loadjava on Oracle using this:

```
loadjava -u testdb/user123@TEST -r -v -f -genmissing -s -grant public ojdbc6.jar
```

and i got lots of errors like this:

> [20:07:47]genmissing: oracle/jdbc/NotificationRegistration
>   [20:07:47]creating : class oracle/jdbc/NotificationRegistration
>   [20:07:47]loading  : class oracle/jdbc/NotificationRegistration
>   [20:07:47]Error while creating class
>   oracle/jdbc/NotificationRegistration [20:07:47]    ORA-29545: 类格式错误:
>   User has attempted to load a class
>   (oracle.jdbc.NotificationRegistration) into a restricted package.
>   Permission can be granted using  dbms_java.grant_permission(,
>   LoadClassInPackage... [20:07:47]ORA-06512: 在 line 1

it seems that 'testdb' need more permissions,so i use 'sys' to grant permission in Oracle:

```
exec dbms_java.grant_permission('TESTDB','SYS:oracle.aurora.security.JServerPermission','LoadClassInPackage.*', null);
```

However,when i tried to load the jar again,i got the same error as before.

What should I do?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the normal user called x and give all the required permission as below, then try it again.

```
CONNECT
RESOURCE
CREATE ANY PROCEDURE
CREATE PROCEDURE
CREATE ANY TABLE
CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: You can refer the Oracle docs at:     https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/loadjava-tool.html#

Comment: i have tried created a new user and gave permission.it doesn't work